# Opening a VS2008 project in Windows 8.1, that was a previously created

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-8.1, word-2003

I am facing a problem when opening af VS2008 solution. The project is a MS Word 2003 Add-in.
The solution was created with VS2008 a while ago, by someone else. 
I have Windows 7, VS2008 and MS Word 2003 installed on my computer and it is(was) working perfectly.

Now I have upgraded my pc to windows 8.1 and installed VS2008 and MS Word 2003 again. 
But when I open my solution in VS2008 (on Windows 8.1) it says the project was created with a previous version of Visual Studio eventhough it is still VS2008, and wants to convert it.
I have tried to convert it, but when I debug it, it says "You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of the Microsoft Office application is not installed".

EDIT: SOLUTION

It was because i had a newer version of Office installed, so Visual Studio automatically tried to upgrade the solution for that one. Two avoid that, I did this in visual studio:
Tools->Options->Office tools->Project Upgrade-> uncheck the "Always upgrade to installed version of Office"

The weird thing was, that Office 2013 was installed, but Visual Studio tried to uprade the solution for Office 2007.

Comment: Do you need the Office dev tools installed?

Comment: maybe. Aren't they installed per default, when you install visual studio?

Comment: Under "About" in Visual Studio, it says that "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office" are installed.

Comment: OH - I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: I figured it out. I added the solution in the question.

Comment: Ahh cool - you might want to add that as the actual answer (then mark is as accepted)